# Unable to install VirtualBox 6.1 in Ubunut 22.04 LTS

Tags: virtualbox, dependencies, 22.04

I am trying to install Virtual-box in my Ubuntu machine, which is of x86_64 architecture.

**Note**: The VirtualBox is to tryout other variants of Ubuntu flavors & other Linux-distros, So if there is a better tool than Virtual box, suggestions are welcome as well.

I am following the guide in [Official VirtualBox Doc](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads),

Steps executed in order,

1. Adding entry in sources.list, (As my distro is jammy & it didn't work, tried both below, But still the same overall outcome)

   - Attempt 1 `deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic contrib`
   - Attempt 2 `deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian eoan contrib`
2. Added the Oracle public keys
3. Updated source list
4. And when i tried to do `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-6.1`

Getting the following error:

```
Reading  package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 virtualbox-6.1 : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libvpx6 (>= 1.6.0) but it is not installable
                  Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And unable to add/install those dependencies as when tried `sudo apt-get install libssl1.1`

As getting the bellow error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libssl1.1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libssl1.1' has no installation candidate
```

Additional Info, In my 'Ubuntu Software' sources to fetch, all 4 tracks are already enabled  `main,universe, restricted, multiverse`

Comment: The `bionic` and `eoan` repositories would certainly not work on Jammy, as the library differences are not insubstantial. Why not install the one that ships in the default repos? `sudo apt install virtualbox` 

Comment: As i followed the official guide, went in the above track! This one from default repos, is it the same/latest version as available from the official site?

Comment: The version supplied by Ubuntu is rarely the most recent, but it's the one that has been confirmed to work. [According to Ubuntu Packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/virtualbox), the current version that is installed is 6.1.32. This is the one that I use on 22.04 and it functions just fine.

Comment: @matigo, True it just works no more issues in installation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @matigo, The 'virtualbox' available from the default repos just works

You may install it in below ways,

- using the apt command `sudo apt install virtualbox`, it will listout all the dependencies to be installed
- using the 'Ubuntu Software', it does all in single click

Then you have to do one more configuration, during install, the steps to add the respective configuration in boot entry will be displayed then it works as charm

Comment: Using the command on 22.10 I get: "Package 'virtualbox' has no installation candidate"